# Data replacement of data A using data B and comes out data B

Tags: php

The teacher table has elements of teacher's name , position, userid and password. I want to replace the `userid` with teacher's name in the another table named `Subject` so that it is easier to refer. So how can I do it using PHP coding ?

```
<?php
    include ('connection.php');
    $data1 = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM teacher");

    while ($info1=mysqli_fetch_array($data1))
    {
        echo "<option hidden selected> -- Your Option -- </option>";
        echo "<option value=$info1[userid]>$info1[name]</option>";  
    }
```

I expect to have the teacher's name as an option but it came out $info1[name]

Comment: Adding the name to a second table is bad design.  OK it means having to join to another table - but it saves having the name on various table which can easily come out of line with each other.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do syntax changes as follows:

```
while ($info1=mysqli_fetch_array($data1))
{
    echo "<option hidden selected> -- Your Option -- </option>";
    echo "<option value='$info1[userid]'>'$info1[name]'</option>";  
}
```

Because PHP take $info1[name] as a string, you need to use single quote to interpret the variable value.

Answer (score 0):

I usually prefer a much clearer syntax, which helps me in checking I refer to all in a correct manner:

```
while ($info1=mysqli_fetch_array($data1))
{
    echo "<option hidden selected> -- Your Option -- </option>";
    echo "<option value=\"".$info1["userid"]."\">".$info1["name"]."</option>";  
}
```

With that syntax you can always be sure, by simply looking at the code, that PHP will recognize and insert proper values...

Also, check that field names in the table do match exactly (even in uppercase/lowercase, not all db configurations are case insensitive) the names you use: "userid", "name", etc.

Comment: If it still doesn't work,what could be the reason causing the problem?

Comment: You mean you've been using the syntax I proposed and it doesn't work? Then it should at least give you an error of some sort... What error?